# Оптимизировать запрос с CASE

Tags: sql

**Подскажите, можно ли как-то оптимизировать данный запрос.Возможно, использование CASE здесь не оптимальное решение?**

Цeль запроса-соединить физических и юридических клиентом, подставив либо их ФИО либо название компании

```
select c.cust_id, CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN name ELSE first_name+ ' ' + last_name END 
from
customer c left join 
business b on c.CUST_ID=b.cust_id 
left join INDIVIDUAL i on c.CUST_ID=i.cust_id
order by CUST_ID
```

Comment: `COALESCE(name, first_name + ' ' + last_name)`. Впрочем, смыслу в такой "оптимизации" - ноль.

Comment: А что в данном случае значит «оптимизировать»?  Где `EXPLAIN`, показывающий проблему, а также тип и версия СУБД?

Comment: Подписываюсь под комментами, ничего не понятно. А так пока пальцем в небо то скорее всего индексы не проставлены